# Authentication Database Fields

Tags: database, database-design

I am implementing an authentication system into an existing database system. Currently, the database has a "Person" table that includes things like: First Name, Last Name, Date of Birth, Email (username), etc. This is the primary table for a user.

I need to add the following fields for authentication: Password, IsLocked, LockDate, LastLoginDate.

Would you suggest putting these fields in the Person table or would you put them in a new Authentication table? My original plan was for "Person" to simply contain data about that person, not necessarily about authentication.

The other approach could be to store the password along with the email in Person, but then place the authentication data in a separate table. This way, the username and password would be in the same place, but the meta data would be in its own entity.

Anyone have any thoughts?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the account information separate.  Your current business requirement may be for each person to have only one account, but it could come up in the future that a person needs to have multiple accounts, or even that you need an account that is shared by multiple people.  Having a separate table for authentication means that such **future changes will have a smaller impact** on your code.

Also, from the perspective of **protecting authentication information**, the fewer people/processes that can access the account data the better off you'll be.  It's much easier to implement table-level access than column-level access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using this approach, where would you store the email address? It is used throughout the application but also doubles as the username. Would you abstract it away from Person and into the Authentication table?

Comment: @user543936 - I would keep the user ID separate from an email address for the same reasons I've noted above.  It may be a coincidence or a policy to use email address as user ID by default, but this could always change in the future if you introduce group logins or email distribution lists, etc.  If you have a business rule that says they should be the same, then write a little bit of application logic that checks before updating one that the other is updated automatically too (as long as they were the same before the edit).

Answer (score 3):

Keep them separate so that users can query the system for information about a `Person` without necessarily having access to their account credentials.

This also has a nice side-effect where not all `Person` entities may have accounts.

Comment: You can give users access to `Person` but not `Authentication` data by creating an appropiate view, that's no big issue.

Comment: @Yuka True. However the model still makes more sense with the related attributes split. Same idea with a `PersonContactInformation` or `PersonAddress` relation. Even if that `Person` will always have **exactly one** of either, there is no sense keeping everything in a single table.

Comment: Yeah... good point, actually. (This, and what ypercube said.) I guess I approached this wrong. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes much sense to create a seperate table for Authentication data. Authentication can't exist independently of the Person, as far as I can tell - and there doesn't seem to be a way one Person could reasonably be associated with two Authentications (or vice versa).

In other words: There's a 1:1 relationship between Person and Authentication, so why split it off?

Comment: This database has a lot of 1:1 relationships, but I have them split off to separate them into logical entities. 

For example, I could put all of the user's career information in the Person table, but it makes more sense to put it in a "Career" table since it could potentially expand into something larger.

I guess I'm just trying to avoid putting EVERY 1:1 relationship in the Person table. I don't want to have a table with 100 columns...so I'm trying to avoid that pitfall early.

Comment: I see; that's true, you don't want to end up with a monstrous single table. I would still recommend keeping Authentication stuff in the main Person table, as I feel it's rather closely tied to the information in there (e. g. the username), but I can see the case against it. It comes down to personal preference, I guess.

Comment: There can be many reasons for multiple authentications per person. Different roles may require a person to have 2 or more passwords. One that gives him simple user access and one that gives him admin access, for example.